# How to remove this error signs in my Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

[image]

It shows too many errors but the codes we're ok.

Comment: Show us what some of the errors are

Answer (score 0):

Put your mouse on the red fork, IDE will display the detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

first check all the methods were define correctly all the required statements should be imports. even though the errors are still then just do one thing.

got Project tab and clean the project.

this is enough for resolving the errors.

Comment: It appears after I update my JRE. I solved the problem already. Thanks!